# Fetching application version from play store inside Android

Tags: android, api, google-play

Here is my problem scenario.

I am working on an application which will essentially search the play store for a set of applications to get their version numbers and check with the versions of installed apps and notify the user if there is an update available.

So I need to know,

1. Is there a way to get the version number of an app from play store? Do google expose any APIs for this purpose? I did something like below from command line using CURL, but got an error.

   ```
   $ curl https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.app.id.here
   curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to play.google.com:443
   ```
2. How can I get the version of an installed app in Android?

   This part is solved using `getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages()`

Comment: There isn't an official API, but [42matters](https://42matters.com/api/lookup) has one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not experience the certificate error with curl.  Perhaps ensure your packages including certificate store are up-to-date?

As a general habit I suggest surrounding the URL in quotes as some common url characters can be interpreted by the shell.  The following snippet retrieves the app version from the play url:

```
$ curl -s 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thoughtcrime.redphone' | xmllint --xpath "//div[@itemprop='softwareVersion']/text()" --html - 2> /dev/null 
 0.9.6
```

I notice that google applications have application versions that vary by device:

```
$ curl -s 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps' | xmllint --xpath "//div[@itemprop='softwareVersion']/text()" --html - 2> /dev/null 
   Varies with device
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow specify the device/platform in the url? E.g. If I know I have a phone, it should be possible to set "...&device=phone" or similar.

Comment: @l33t Yes, you can add parameters to the URL like you suggested.  The single quotes should keep you from having to escape the & in order to prevent it from being interpreted by the shell.  You can also change the referer with the `-e` option in curl.

Comment: Ok. But which parameter controls the device info? Does the Google Play web even care about the device?

Comment: I have not looked at google play closely in quite a long time.  My somewhat cloudy recollection is that apps that target a specific platform or geo location are filtered if you do not meet the criteria.  I suspect the referer is more likely used than a url param, but some research or testing would be necessary.