Is there an API to retrieve an app's latest version from the Google Play Store?
For context, I'm attempting to trigger a Github actions workflow when the app version on the Google Play Store matches the version I'm interested in. I have not been able to find an API that allows me to query the app's Play Store version. The closest answers I saw were https://stackoverflow.com/a/23505064/2688283 and How to get the app's latest version from Google play? but those no longer work, since Google recently updated the Play Store app details page.

There is the play publisher API which allows you to edit releases and probably allows you to read the latest version by starting an edit and discarding it. Not ideal nor a good indicator whether the app is actually available to users. I guess publishers just flip a switch manually when they know the release is out (for example publish a txt file on github with the latest publicly available version number and trigger on that files content, then automate your calender to remind you to update that file :D )

Thanks for responding! I'll take a look at the publisher API.
